# How can I start a subprocess in Python that runs independently and continues running if the main process is closed?

Tags: python, flask, subprocess

I have a small Flask API that is receiving requests from a remote server. Whenever a request is received, a subprocess is started. This subprocess is simply executing a second Python file that is in the same folder. This subprocess can run for several hours and several of these subprocesses can run simultaneously. I am using stdout to write the output of the python file into a text file.

All of this is working fine, but every couple of weeks it happens that the Flask API becomes unresponsive and needs to be restarted. As soon as I stop the Flask server, all running subprocesses stop. I would like to avoid this and run each subprocess independently from the flask API.

This is a small example that illustrates what I am doing (this code is basically inside a method that can be called through the API)

```
import subprocess

f = open("log.txt","wb")
subprocess.Popen(["python","job.py"],cwd = "./", stdout = f, stderr = f)
```

I would like to achieve that the subprocess keeps running after I stop the Flask API. This is currently not the case. Somewhere else I read that the reason is that I am using the stdout and stderr parameters, but even after removing those the behavior stays the same.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: glancing at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) there's a `creationflags` which if set to `subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` the new process has a new console, instead of inheriting its parent’s console (the default). Not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Man the cwd parameter helped me alot. Thanks for creating this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sub-processes stop because their parent process dies when you restart your Flask server. You need to completely separate your sub-processes from your Flask process by running your Python call in a new shell:

```
from subprocess import call

# On Linux:
command = 'gnome-terminal -x bash -l -c "python job.py"'
# On Windows:
# command = 'cmd /c "python job.py"'
call(command, shell=True)
```

This way your Python call of job.py will run in a separate terminal window, unaffected by your Flask server process.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to get very close to what I want. The process indeed continues when the Flask server is closed. However, the method inside the flask server doesn't continue after this call. I have tried executing this inside a separate thread as follows: 

`def start_job():
    command = 'cmd /c "python job.py > log.txt"'
    subprocess.call(command, shell=True, cwd = "jobs/jobid/")
thread = threading.Thread(target = start_job, args = [])
thread.start()`

That solves the problem that the method continues, but when I now close the Flask server, the process terminates again.

Comment: As far as I understand, you need to completely separate your child processes from your main Flask process, right? I recommend you include your entire subprocess call in a Python file that you write out and execute from the new shell. If you write out a new Python file with all the necessary methods that need to be run, you don't really need threading. Each new terminal shell call is essentially a new thread, since it's in its own shell. Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm glad this helped. If you found my answer/comments helpful please consider up-voting them, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use fork() to create a child process of the process in which you are calling this function. On successful fork(), it returns a zero for the child id.

Below is a basic example of fork, which you can easily incorporate in your code.

```
import os
pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0:  # new process
    os.system("nohup python ./job.py &")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. That seems to work on Linux, but unfortunately this flask server is running on a windows server (it relies on some software that is not available on Linux). Turns out the os.fork method can only be used on Linux.